# Permission request dialog is not taking into account app's locale

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am setting the locale in my app like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

But when calling to request permissions

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
           new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
```

the dialog created by the OS doesn't take into account the app's locale, it's using the system locale.

So if device is set to `English` and my app is set to `Spanish` the permission request dialog will use `English`.

Is there a way to make the dialog use app's locale instead (`Spanish`)?

Comment: Any system-supplied UI, such as the permission dialog, will use the language chosen by the user for their device. You cannot affect this.

Comment: Isn't this an issue? Not being able to fully localize your app?